# Web interface or tool for developers to run select query with out access database directly

Tags: sql-server, mysql, mysqldump

I want a tool or web interface that can allow inside users (developers,..) to run select query with out access the database directly. 
I don't want to give sql user to all the developers for the database, so the can't allow to run dump on the database.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

That's less of a tool question, and more of a permissions question. You can let them run queries with SQL Server Management Studio or Azure Data Studio, but just configure their permissions so that they can't write data or take backups.

One way to get started is to [give their logins the db_datareader and db_denydatawriter roles](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1900/understanding-sql-server-fixed-database-roles/). That way they can read, but not write.

Comment: It appears that his main concern is to stop the developers from "dumping," which I assume means exporting entire tables, and a web interface could be coded to limit the amount of data returned...

Comment: Tools like that are pretty easy to work around - you just select ranges of data each time.

Comment: In sql server in mysql I don't have this option

Comment: And I write that for mysql server